# "org.netezza.error.NzSQLexception:ERROR " >>Telend to NETEZZA group by / subquery error

Tags: talend, netezza

I am trying to add component 'tNetezzainput' in Talend
with query like

```
select col1,col2 from
 (select col1,col2 from tab2 )
```

when i run sub query independently it is allowing to get schema
but when i run above query it is showing error like

> org.netezza.error.NzSQLexception:ERROR
>
> (above query)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an alias after the parentheses (I randomly chose ‘x’):

```
select col1,col2 from
 (select col1,col2 from tab2 ) x
```

Comment: thank you alias was the issue...

seems netezza does not show error clearly .. is there any way to find out where  the error exactly is in Netezza sql